# Tracking WeakReference to objects from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, delegates, garbage-collection, weak-references

I am designing a static message bus that would allow subscribing to and publishing of messages of an arbitrary type. To avoid requiring observers to unsubscribe explicitly, I would like to keep track of WeakReference objects that point to delegates instead of tracking delegates themselves. I ended up coding something similar to what Paul Stovell described in his blog http://www.paulstovell.com/weakevents.

My problem is this: as opposed to Paul's code, my observers subscribe to messages on one thread, but messages may be published on another. In this case, I observe that by the time I need to notify observers, my WeakReference.Target values are null indicating that targets have been collected, even though I know for certain they weren't. The problem persists for both short and long weak references.

Conversely, when subscribing and publishing is done from the same thread, the code works fine. The latter is true even if I actually end up enumerating over targets on a new thread from ThreadPool, for as long as the request initially comes from the same thread I subscribe to messages on.

I understand that this is a very specific case, so any help is greatly appreciated.

**My question is:** should I not be able to reliably access WeakReference objects from multiple threads provided proper thread synchronization is in place? It appears that I cannot, which does not make much sense to me. So, what am I not doing right?

Comment: And your question is? (please state it in the form of a question)

Comment: Also, what language/platform are we talking about here?  Java?  C#?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using C# with .NET 4.0 in VS2010. The question is this: should I not be able to reliably access WeakReference objects from multiple threads provided proper thread synchronization is in place? It appears that I cannot, which does not make much sense to me. So, what am I not doing right?

Comment: sorry, I hit Return to quickly. I can't copy all of my code, but I can put together a representative example, if need be.

Comment: Yeah, could you please post a small sample?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after reducing my code to a simpler form (see below), it now works fine. This means, the problem that caused weak reference targets to be collected too early must reside elsewhere in my code. So, to answer my own question, it appears that weak references can be securely accessed from multiple threads.

Here is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting the app");
            Test test = new Test();
            // uncomment these lines to cause automatic unsubscription from Message1
//          test = null;
//          GC.Collect();
//          GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            // publish Message1 on this thread
            // MessageBus.Publish<Message1>(new Message1());

            // publish Message1 on another thread
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                MessageBus.Publish<Message1>(new Message1());
            });


            while (!MessageBus.IamDone)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting the app");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate program.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribing to message 1.");
            MessageBus.Subscribe<Message1>(OnMessage1);
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribing to message 2.");
            MessageBus.Subscribe<Message2>(OnMessage2);
        }

        public void OnMessage1(Message1 message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got message 1. Publishing message 2");
            MessageBus.Publish<Message2>(new Message2());
        }

        public void OnMessage2(Message2 message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got message 2. Closing the app");
            MessageBus.IamDone = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract class MessageBase
    {
        public string Message;
    }

    public class Message1 : MessageBase
    {
    }

    public class Message2 : MessageBase
    {
    }

    public static class MessageBus
    {
        // This is here purely for this test
        public static bool IamDone = false;
        /////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// A dictionary of lists of handlers of messages by message type
        /// </summary>
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<WeakReference>> handlersDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<WeakReference>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Thread synchronization object to use with Publish calls
        /// </summary>
        private static object _lockPublishing = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Thread synchronization object to use with Subscribe calls
        /// </summary>
        private static object _lockSubscribing = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a work queue item that encapsulates the provided parameterized message
        /// and dispatches it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TMessage">Message argument type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="message">Message argument</param>
        public static void Publish<TMessage>(TMessage message)
            where TMessage : MessageBase
        {
            // create the dictionary key
            string key = String.Empty;
            key = typeof(TMessage).ToString();
            // initialize a queue work item argument as a tuple of the dictionary type key and the message argument
            Tuple<string, TMessage, Exception> argument = new Tuple<string, TMessage, Exception>(key, message, null);
            // push the message on the worker queue
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(_PublishMessage<TMessage>), argument);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Publishes a message to the bus, causing observers to be invoked if appropriate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TArg">Message argument type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="stateInfo">Queue work item argument</param>
        private static void _PublishMessage<TArg>(Object stateInfo)
            where TArg : class
        {
            try
            {
                // translate the queue work item argument to extract the message type info and
                // any arguments
                Tuple<string, TArg, Exception> arg = (Tuple<string, TArg, Exception>)stateInfo;
                // call all observers that have registered to receive this message type in parallel
                Parallel.ForEach(handlersDict.Keys
                    // find the right dictionary list entry by message type identifier
                    .Where(handlerKey => handlerKey == arg.Item1)
                    // dereference the list entry by message type identifier to get a reference to the observer
                    .Select(handlerKey => handlersDict[handlerKey]), (handlerList, state) =>
                    {
                        lock (_lockPublishing)
                        {
                            List<int> descopedRefIndexes = new List<int>(handlerList.Count);
                            // search the list of references and invoke registered observers
                            foreach (WeakReference weakRef in handlerList)
                            {
                                // try to obtain a strong reference to the target
                                Delegate dlgRef = (weakRef.Target as Delegate);
                                // check if the underlying delegate reference is still valid
                                if (dlgRef != null)
                                {
                                    // yes it is, get the delegate reference via Target property, convert it to Action and invoke the observer
                                    try
                                    {
                                        (dlgRef as Action<TArg>).Invoke(arg.Item2);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        // trouble invoking the target observer's reference, mark it for deletion
                                        descopedRefIndexes.Add(handlerList.IndexOf(weakRef));
                                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error looking up target reference: {0}", e.Message));
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // the target observer's reference has been descoped, mark it for deletion
                                    descopedRefIndexes.Add(handlerList.IndexOf(weakRef));
                                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message type \"{0}\" has been unsubscribed from.", arg.Item1));
                                    MessageBus.IamDone = true;
                                }
                            }
                            // remove any descoped references
                            descopedRefIndexes.ForEach(index => handlerList.RemoveAt(index));
                        }
                    });
            }
            // catch all Exceptions
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error dispatching messages: {0}", e.Message));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subscribes the specified delegate to handle messages of type TMessage
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TArg">Message argument type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="action">WeakReference that represents the handler for this message type to be registered with the bus</param>
        public static void Subscribe<TArg>(Action<TArg> action)
            where TArg : class
        {
            // validate input
            if (action == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(String.Format("Error subscribing to message type \"{0}\": Specified action reference is null.", typeof(TArg)));
            // build the queue work item key identifier
            string key = typeof(TArg).ToString();
            // check if a message of this type was already added to the bus
            if (!handlersDict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                // no, it was not, create a new dictionary entry and add the new observer's reference to it
                List<WeakReference> newHandlerList = new List<WeakReference>();
                handlersDict.TryAdd(key, newHandlerList);
            }
            lock (_lockSubscribing)
            {
                // append this new observer's reference to the list, if it does not exist already
                if (!handlersDict[key].Any(existing => (existing.Target as Delegate) != null && (existing.Target as Delegate).Equals(action)))
                {
                    // append the new reference
                    handlersDict[key].Add(new WeakReference(action, true));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an amendment to my previous answer. I have discovered why my original code did not work and this information may be useful for others. In my original code MessageBus was instantiated as Singleton:

```
public class MessageBus : Singleton<MessageBus> // Singleton<> is my library class
```

In the example above, it was declared as static:

```
public static class MessageBus
```

Once I converted my code to use a static, things started working. Having said that, I could not yet figure out why the singleton did not work.